# AbsoluteLayout - Measure Label Height without placing label on UI

Tags: xamarin.forms, label, measure, absolutelayout

I am manually positioning labels in an AbsoluteLayout.
To do this correctly I would like to know the label height prior to placing it on the UI.

I have found this solution, but not without actually placing a label:

```
public double MeasureLabelHeight(string text, double width, double fontSize, double lineHeight, string fontFamily)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.WidthRequest = width;
        label.FontSize = fontSize;
        label.LineHeight = lineHeight;
        label.FontFamily = fontFamily;
        label.LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap;
        label.Text = text;
        MyAbsoluteLayout.Children.Add(view: label, position: new Point(0, Height)); //place out of sight
        var sizeRequest = label.Measure(widthConstraint: width, heightConstraint: double.MaxValue, flags: MeasureFlags.None);
        var labelTextHeight = sizeRequest.Request.Height;
        MyAbsoluteLayout.Children.Remove(label);
        return labelTextHeight;
    }
```

This solution works on UWP, I still have to test it on Android and iOS.

I would like to improve on it though.
I am unable to get a correct Height value without actually placing it in the AbsoluteLayout (out of view) and am a bit worried about the overhead this probably causes with extra redraws.

I have found an [old piece of code](https://gist.github.com/alexrainman/82b00160ab32bef9e69dee6d460f44fa) that seemingly uses native code to do this without actually placing it in the UI for iOS and Android. I'm wondering if there is a solution available that has no need for platform specific code.

Answer (score 0):

Let Xamarin Forms measure them for you. Then you move them into position.

Do this by subclassing `AbsoluteLayout`, and adding an `Action` that a page can set, to be called when your layout has done `LayoutChildren`.

MyAbsoluteLayout.cs:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    public class MyAbsoluteLayout : AbsoluteLayout
    {
        public MyAbsoluteLayout()
        {
        }

        // Containing page will set this, to act on children during LayoutChildren.
        public Action CustomLayoutAction { get; set; }

        private bool _busy;

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            // Avoid recursed layout calls as CustomLayoutAction moves children.
            if (_busy)
                return;

            // Xamarin measures the children.
            base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);

            _busy = true;
            try
            {
                CustomLayoutAction?.Invoke();
            }
            finally
            {
                _busy = false;
                // Layout again, to position the children, based on adjusted (x,y)s.
                base.LayoutChildren(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage - MyAbsoluteLayoutPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XFSOAnswers"
             x:Class="XFSOAnswers.MyAbsoluteLayoutPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <local:MyAbsoluteLayout x:Name="TheLayout">
            <!-- Layout positions start (0,0). Adjusted later in PositionLabels. -->
            <Label x:Name="Label1" Text="Welcome" />
            <Label x:Name="Label2" Text="to" />
            <Label x:Name="Label3" Text="Xamarin" />
            <Label x:Name="Label4" Text=".Forms!" />
        </local:MyAbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

MyAbsoluteLayoutPage.xaml.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MyAbsoluteLayoutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyAbsoluteLayoutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TheLayout.CustomLayoutAction = PositionLabels;
        }

        private void PositionLabels()
        {
            // Optional: Set breakpoint after these, to check that the bounds have values.
            var bounds1 = Label1.Bounds;
            var bounds2 = Label2.Bounds;
            var bounds3 = Label3.Bounds;
            var bounds4 = Label4.Bounds;

            double x = 10;
            double y = 20;
            MoveAbsoluteChildTo(Label1, x, y);
            x += Label1.Width;
            y += Label1.Height;

            MoveAbsoluteChildTo(Label2, x, y);
            x += Label2.Width;
            y += Label2.Height;

            MoveAbsoluteChildTo(Label3, x, y);
            x += Label3.Width;
            y += Label3.Height;

            MoveAbsoluteChildTo(Label4, x, y);
        }

        private static void MoveAbsoluteChildTo(View child, double x, double y)
        {
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(child, new Rect(x, y, child.Width, child.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of AbsoluteLayout text]

---

See `MyAbsoluteLayout` and `MyAbsoluteLayoutPage` in [ToolmakerSteve - repo XFormsSOAnswers](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/XFormsSOAnswers).